# Where does CHEESE store its images?

Tags: filesystem, 14.10, cheese

I have taken some pictures using `CHEESE`, but now I cannot locate those images, so I can do nothing with them. I can't even delete them for the CHEESE GUI does not allow me to do anything with the image (although it does display it).

I read [here on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=878249) that the images would be located under `~/.gnome2/cheese/media`, but in the `.gnome` folder there is no folder called `cheese` and I have searched my system for the folders, `cheese` and `media`, but found no folders containing my images.

So my question is, where does CHEESE store its images in my system?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.10.

Information on my CHEESE package:

```
cheese:
   Installed: 3.12.2-1ubuntu2
   Candidate: 3.12.2-1ubuntu2  
   Version table:  
 *** 3.12.2-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mine are saved in `~/Pictures/Webcam`. Also, I can right-click the images in cheese then a menu will pop up with the options: *Open*, *Save As...*, *Move to Trash* and *Delete*.

Comment: Mine doesn't show the options which you describe.

Comment: But the images are located there. Thanks!

Comment: Found mine in `~/Webcam`. Ubuntu 18.04 here.

Comment: The pictures are in `~/Pictures/Webcam`, and the videos are in `~/Videos/Webcam`.